# Photoshop: how to select multiple paths on different layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, selections, cs3

I want to use [this script](http://blog.tonton-pixel.com/scripts/utility-scripts/get-svg-code-from-path/) and to use it I have to select a path, which is fine, and it works.

But how do I select multiple paths, which are on different layers?

I've tried using the Path Selection Tool, and holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and combinations of these, I just can't get Photoshop CS3 to select multiple paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot select multiple paths in different layers.

If you have paths in multiple layers, use the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd> and select one of the paths. Cut and select the target layer. Paste your path there. Repeat until all your paths are in one layer. Now you can select all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge different layers into one layer by following these steps:

1. Select all path layers
2. Then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

If this does not work then you'll need to copy this different path layer one by one and paste it in a main layer. Then adjust this paths.